# Bokeh duplicating values on same plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a bokeh plot that is duplicating values every time the cell is run onto the graph like this:

[image]

This is the block of code, using data from an oracle database connection

```
from bokeh.models import DaysTicker, FuncTickFormatter,SingleIntervalTicker, FixedTicker
source = ColumnDataSource(df_ora)
x = df_ora['DAY']
y = df_ora["ORANGES"]


labels = LabelSet(x='DAY', y= 'ORANGES', text='oranges', level='glyph',
           x_offset=5, y_offset=25, source=source, render_mode='canvas')


p2 = figure(title="",x_axis_type="datetime",y_range=(0,8000), plot_width=1500, plot_height=1000)
p2.line('DAY', 'ORANGES', source=source,line_width=2)
p2.add_layout(Title(text="Date", align="center"), "below")
p2.xaxis.ticker=DaysTicker(days=np.arange(0,32))

p2.add_layout(labels)
p2.circle(x=x, y=y,size=5)
```

My solution was to do a

```
curdoc.clear()
```

However, that still didn't work. All other graphs update normally except this line plot.

Comment: Tried this:`r = p2.text(x=[], y=[], text=[], text_color=[])
i = 0

ds = r.data_source

def callback():
    global i
    ds.data['x'].append(np.random.random()*70 + 15)
    ds.data['y'].append(np.random.random()*70 + 15)
    ds.data['text'].append(str(i))
    ds.trigger('data', ds.data, ds.data)
    i = i + 1

curdoc().add_root(column(p2))
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(callback, 1000)` Didn't work, gave me the error :`Models must be owned by only a single document, HoverTool(id='8473', ...) is already in a doc`

Comment: Have you inspected the data you are passing to Bokeh to verify that the duplication is not occurring earlier in your codepath?

Comment: Yes I verified there is a value for each day in the dataframe. I am wondering if I should remove GlyhRenderers

Comment: I don't really understand your suggestion, and i would say more information (esp about how you are using/embedding Bokeh is needed). You seem to be calling `figure` which will 100% make a new plot. If looping, I might expect *mutiple plots* but the only way for things to appear on the *same plot* is for the data to somehow be duplicated at the time things are shown.

Comment: @bigreddot Seems legit. It might be that I am grabbing multiple rows of the same day into my plot. It doesn't seem to be reading what the oracle database shows.